# How embed HTML file (exported from Plotly) to Jupiter Notebook?

Tags: python, plotly

I need to include this graph https://plot.ly/~ekirzhner/6/ into my Jupiter Notebook. How to proceed? Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to be an interactive graph? Or do you just want to load a png or jpeg image of the graph into jupyter notebook?

Comment: @David Rosenman Interactive html graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on "share" at the bottom right of the image. If you embed it as an iframe, use a code cell. You'll get an interactive graph if you copy and paste this code into the cell.

```
import IPython
iframe = '<iframe width="900" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//plot.ly/~ekirzhner/6.embed"></iframe>'
IPython.display.HTML(iframe)
```

To import a static graph using html, in a markdown cell, use the following code:

```
%%html

<div>
    <a href="https://plot.ly/~ekirzhner/6/" target="_blank" title="Plot 6" style="display: block; text-align: center;"><img src="https://plot.ly/~ekirzhner/6.png" alt="Plot 6" style="max-width: 100%;width: 600px;"  width="600" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://plot.ly/404.png';" /></a>
```

I created a notebook file that contains a static graph from the html option plus a cell with the interactive plotly graph that you can download [here](https://gist.github.com/DRosenman/c7064d420625c0b9cc31a1e3a0964739)